# Data returned from the function comes to snapshot as null

Tags: function, flutter, dart, parameters, snapshot

```
...
Future<List<ProDetails>> getBasket() async {
  sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String userDetails =
      sharedPreferences.getString(AppConnection.CART_DETAILS.toString());
  print("userDetails : " "${userDetails}");
  Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(userDetails);
  print("map result : " + "${map}");
  List<ProDetails> cartList;
  cartList = (json.decode(userDetails) as List)
      .map((i) => ProDetails.fromJson(i))
      .toList();
  return cartList;
}
...
```

Here I send the cart list and try to get it in the below code.

```
...
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getBasket(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              print("Snapshot data : " + "${snapshot.data}");
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Container(
                              child: Text("test" + "${index}"),
                            );
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          )),

...
```

Here it snapshot.data gets null and the page is loading.

The console result is as follows,
...
I/flutter (23990): Snapshot data : null
I/flutter (23990): userDetails : [{"productId":"117","productName":"MACC Tea Master
Blend 40 Bags","category_name":"01 Box (40
Bags)","price":"1.00","quantity":"1","imgUrl":"1605262901.jpg"}]
...
I/flutter (23990): Snapshot data : null

Comment: add the detail of `ProDetails` and `ProDetails.fromJson` method.

Comment: Try to change `if (snapshot.data == null)` insted of if `(snapshot.hasData == null)`

Answer (score 0):

I think your future is throwing and this would result in null data in the builder.

Given the JSON you have the `json.decode` should be returning `List<dynamic>`. Each item in the list in a JSON object so we need to cast each item in the list to a `Map<String, dynamic>`

I think this should be valid given the JSON.

```dart
final json = jsonDecode(data) as List;
final cartList = json
       .map((i) => ProDetails.fromJson(i as Map<String, dynamic>))
       .toList();
```

Here is a test I used to validate the decode.

```dart
const data = '''
[{
  "productId":"117",
  "productName":"MACC Tea Master Blend 40 Bags",
  "category_name":"01 Box (40 Bags)",
  "price":"1.00",
  "quantity":"1",
  "imgUrl":"1605262901.jpg"
}]
''';

void main() {
  test('can decode JSON', () async {
    final json = jsonDecode(data) as List;
    final cartList = json
        .map((i) => ProDetails.fromJson(i as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();

    expect(cartList[0].productId, '117');
  });
}
```

Comment: @ImzarAhamed Ah yer, Sorry about that. I updated the answer with a test.

Answer (score 0):

try change the value of "future" inside the FutureBuilder

```
Future getBasketFuture = getBasket();
FutureBUilder(
  future: getBasketFuture
);
```

you can define the getBasketFuture on the initState